# How to update a text in a view on button click from another view in WPF Prism?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, prism

I'm new to Prism and I'm trying to update a text in MainWindow.xaml another view in region.

## MainWindowViewModel

```
private string _message = "Prism";
public string Message
{
    get { return _message; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _message, value);}
}
```

## MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="XXXX.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Title="{Binding Title}">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="48"></TextBlock>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ViewARegion" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

## ViewAViewModel

```
public ICommand ClickCommand
{
    get;
    private set;
}
public ViewAViewModel()
{
    ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClickedMethod);
}

private void ClickedMethod()
{
    MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    mainWindowViewModel.Message = "Prism View A";
}
```

## ViewA.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXXX.Views.ViewA"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XXXX.Views"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Click"
             Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now when I click the button it's working correctly I mean it's setting the Message property in MainWindowViewModel but it's not udating the View in MainWindow.xaml.
What should I do to get this working as I'm expecting to update the view on button click?

Comment: What makes you believe that if you create a new instance of a class and change a property on that instance that this should change the property on another instance of that class?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
> mainWindowViewModel.Message = "Prism View A";
> ```

This creates a *new* instance of `MainWindowViewModel` that has nothing to do with the instance that's bound to your `MainWindow`. You can change properties on this new instance all day long, the real view model will not care.

You have to implement some view model to view model communication mechanism, e.g. use `IEventAggregator` or a shared service, so that the information ("click happened" or "message changed" or whatever) can be passed from `ViewA` to the `MainWindow`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the event aggregator to send an event from `ViewAViewModel` to `MainWindowViewModel`:

```
public class ViewAViewModel
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public ViewAViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClickedMethod);
    }

    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void ClickedMethod()
    {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<string>>().Publish("Prism View A");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<MessageSentEvent>().Subscribe(MessageReceived);
    }

    private void MessageReceived(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    private string _message = "Prism";
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _message, value); }
    }
}
```

There is a complete example available on GitHub: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/14-UsingEventAggregator